# Resource DialogBox is returning -1

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources

I've created my dialog as a resource using the resource editor (dialog editor?)

It's nothing special, just two groupboxes, two buttons, a split button, two pictureboxes, 3 static labels, 3 edit boxes, 3 spin controls, 3 syslinks, and a progressbar.

When I press Ctrl+T to test the dialog, it appears to work fine, but when I press F5 to debug the program, the dialog never appears and the program exits with code -1 (0xffffffff)

Here is the code I'm using to call the dialog:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
        case (WM_COMMAND):
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    int ret = DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINWINDOW), NULL, DlgProc);

    int err = GetLastErro(); // This gives 0

    return ret; // This gives -1
}
```

I don't have anything yet in the `DlgProc` yet because I just wanted the dialog to show to begin with.

If I set a breakpoint in `DlgProc` then these are the messages it receives:

48, 85, 297, 273, 273, 144, 2, and 130.

I've looked these up and they translate to:

```
WM_SETFONT
WM_NOTIFYFORMAT
???
WM_COMMAND
WM_COMMAND
???
WM_DESTROY
WM_NCDESTROY
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**:
I found a solution to the problem! We originally thought it was a corrupted RC file but I realised the the test RC file I made has every type of control except a SysLink. When I added a SysLink the same thing happened. I tried including ComCtl32.lib in the linker, and I also tried including the common controls header and calling `InitCommonControls` but that did nothing.

I put everything back the way it originally was, and added this pre-processor directive which fixed it:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

That was the problem. Without that directive, the dialog won't initialise because of the SysLinks!

Comment: I had this same problem in Visual C++ 2010. Only it would work in release builds, but not in debug builds. It turned out the problem was the "Resource File Name" property was empty in the Debug configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `DefWindowProc` for Dialog procs. They are done for you by the OS. simply `return FALSE;`

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the answer for you in the previous question. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#modal_box for detailed example on how to create a modal dialog

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have made the changes but this did not fix the problem. It's still exiting with -1

Comment: Instead of doing `return DialogBox(...)`, call `GetLastError()` afterwards to get the error code after calling DialogBox

Comment: `GetLastError()` after `DialogBox()` returns 0. I suspect that means there was no error? Maybe there is something wrong with my resource file? Shall I PasteBin it?

Comment: Try following the example first before doing anything fancier. It should work. it will also help you do it properly.

Comment: corrupt .rc file was the problem. But be sure to still check out the example

Comment: See updated question: Corruption not the problem after all. The test RC file I made had all controls except a SysLink. As soon as I added it the same thing happened. I have posted the solution at the end of the question. That pre-processor directive *was* originally there, but I deleted it accidentally at some stage, and didn't realise that's when the whole thing stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Common controls! Progress bar, as an example - you'd need linkage with commctrl dll, inclusion of commctrl header, and call to InitCommonControlsEx. This is causing your program to execute and immediately terminate.

---

Testing your dialog from within the resource editor doesn't actually execute any of the rest of your code - it merely draws the dialog, draws the child windows in the appropriate places, and then sits there and stares at you. Your dlgproc can be terribly incorrect and the resource editor won't so much as whimper.

Your dialog procedure should return 0 by default, not hand off to the default window proc.

Once you're rolling, you would handle (some of) the messages your dialog receives with something like this:

```
 switch(msg) {
      case WM_COMMAND:{
           switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
              // do stuff here when a child window is manipulated
      }
      break;
 }
```

Comment: I have written a few of these before, but did not know that `DefWindowProc` doesn't need to be called for Dialogs. Please see my updated question. Even with a fixed `DlgProc` I have exactly the same result.

Comment: Does IDD_MAINWINDOW correspond to your actual resource? Obviously, it's defined in resource.h; otherwise, you'd get an error. In other words, did the resource ID of your dialog change, and you've not reflected that change in your code?

Comment: Ah, common controls! Progress bar gave it away, and no inclusion of commctrl header. Assuming no linkage with commctrl dll, either, and certainly no InitCommonControlsEx call in your code. Remove the controls; strip to bare plain jane controls, like a cancel button, then rebuild and see. Also, you'll have to kill the process, as your dlgproc in its form shown here doesn't call EndDialog as a result of any particular message.

Comment: Very close, but not quite. But you did point me in the right direction. See updated question for the solution. In the end I did not have to include the header, or `InitCommonControlsEx`, or ComCtl32.lib at all. Just the preprocessor directive!

Comment: Glad to hear you're up and running! You could have done it long hand without the #pragma, but that's perfectly fine. Good luck!